# MAAS Commissioned node does not boot - no bootable medium found

Tags: virtualbox, maas

I just installed MAAS in a test environment, i.e., I set up two VMs in VirtualBox.

VM 1 runs the MAAS server and has two "virtual NICs". The first one is NATed to the outside network and the second one has a VBox host-only network without VBox's own DHCP server.

VM 2 only has one virtual NIC connected to the host-only network.

When I PXE-boot VM 2, it enlists correctly, and I can commission it. The commissioning completes and shows no error. When the node is ready as of the web interface, I start it from VBox, but then it says:

```
"FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted."
```

What might I be missing?

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. I tried the same setup on physical computers, and there I have the same problem. The symptom is that the hard drives do not even get partitioned. One of the machines had a system on before I wanted to integrate it into the MAAS, and after the commissioning was successful as of the web interface, it still booted the old system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved it. I incorrectly understood how MAAS worked, and unfortunately the documentation is not very clear about it. "Ready" only means that the node can be used, it does NOT mean that there is already an OS on it at that point.

I just went on into the documentation and bootstrapped Juju, et voila, when I started my nodes, one of them PXE-booted and installed the system.

I thought it worked like the other automatic methods of installation I know: Commissioning puts a basic OS on the node, and when it is ready, this basic OS is installed. The documentation should maybe point out that this is NOT the case.